# How to send updates to the VM which is DevTest lab in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template

I have a VM in azure DevTest lab. This VM is deployed using custom image(client provided). If is there any updates to this custom image or any OS updates. How we apply these new changes to the VM in DevTest Lab. I found that update management using runs is the solution for applying patches to VM. Is there any other way or update management is only solution for this ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK currently [Update Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-update-management) is the recommended and only best approach because it helps to easily manage OS updates for your multiple Windows and Linux machines in Azure, in on-premises environments, and in other cloud environments as well.